# Deny access to folder but allow access to a file inside that folder

Tags: asp.net, webforms, authorization

I would like to deny anonymous users access to the folder 'test' but exclude and allow access to a file 'webform1' inside the test folder.  Why does this not work?

```
<location path="test">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
<location path="test/webform1">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Here is a link to a sample webforms project https://github.com/uselesshasid/StackOverflow_Question_38597397

Comment: Tried changing the order?

Comment: same question. tried alot of things without luck

Comment: @boruchsiper I answered the question my self. Maybe it will solve the issue for you too.

Comment: don't forget to mark your answer as the aswer

Comment: @boruchsiper It only allows accepting one's own answer after two days. patience is a virtue :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a bug in asp.net, with the way it handles authorization when friendly url's are used.

I changed the web.config to define by versions of the file url, and it works.

```
<location path="test/webform1">
<system.web>
   <authorization>
     <allow users="*"/>
   </authorization>
</system.web>
<location path="test/webform1.aspx">
<system.web>
   <authorization>
     <allow users="*"/>
   </authorization>
</system.web>
```