# Allow access to all users to specific page within restricted folder

Tags: asp.net, webforms, web-config

I have a folder "qc" which is only allowed for the role "warehouse".
In that folder i have a page that I want anyone to access without logging in.

Here's what I've done with web.config but it still redirects me to the login page:

```
<location path="QC/MyPage.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
        <allow roles="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="QC">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
        <allow roles="warehouse" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As aswered [her](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38597397/deny-access-to-folder-except-one-file-in-asp-net) you need to repeat it without the aspx extension.

```
<location path="test/webform1">
<system.web>
   <authorization>
     <allow users="*"/>
   </authorization>
</system.web>
<location path="test/webform1.aspx">
<system.web>
   <authorization>
     <allow users="*"/>
   </authorization>
</system.web>
```